# How to solve a string to data conversion problem on a Django template

Tags: python, json, django

I have a string to data conversion problem on a Django template. I'm trying to take a string (of a date) and calculate the days since that date; so it says something like "1 month, 2 weeks (since all time high date)". The string to date conversion is working fine, the problem is on the Django template. The template currently shows only the last date from the json data request for each item in returned in the for loop. Obviously I need the date for each specific record converted and displayed.

I've formatted the string from the json data request into date object.

Currently only the last item in the list is being sent as the `days_since_ath_formatted` variable.

Here's the Django view def:

```
coin_list_url = f"https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page={per_page_limit}&page=1&sparkline=false"

    request_coin_list = requests.get(coin_list_url)
    results_coin_list = request_coin_list.json()

    crypto_data_geckco = []


#string to date conversion

    def to_string(time):
        return time.strftime('%Y %M %d')

    def from_string(date, formatting):
        dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, formatting)
        return dt

#for loop
    for currency_gecko in results_coin_list:
        days_since_ath = currency_gecko['ath_date']
        days_since_ath_formatted = from_string(days_since_ath[:-14], "%Y-%m-%d")
        print('days since ath formatted', days_since_ath_formatted)
        crypto_data_geckco.append(currency_gecko)
        print("crypto_data_geckco", crypto_data_geckco)


    return render(request, 'crypto/latest.html', { 'crypto_data_geckco': crypto_data_geckco, 'days_since_ath_formatted': days_since_ath_formatted} )
```

and then on the Django template:

```
{% for currency in crypto_data_geckco %}

    All-Time Percentage: {{ currency.ath_change_percentage|intword }}%

    and passing the "days_since_ath_formatted" variable only accesses the last item in the list:

    Days since ATH: {{ days_since_ath_formatted|timesince }}

{% endfor %}
```

The `{{ days_since_ath_formatted|timesince }}` should display a different date for each item returned in the for loop. At the moment it only displays the last item in json list for each item in the for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're actually storing the value of days_since_ath_formatted when looping over this list, you probably want to store in a dict:

```
for currency_gecko in results_coin_list:
    currency = {}
    currency['ath_change_percentage'] = currency_gecko.ath_change_percentage
    currency['days_since_ath_formatted'] = from_string(days_since_ath[:-14], "%Y-%m-%d")
    print('days since ath formatted', days_since_ath_formatted)
    crypto_data_geckco.append(currency)
    print("crypto_data_geckco", currency)


return render(request, 'crypto/latest.html', { 'crypto_data_geckco': crypto_data_geckco, 'days_since_ath_formatted': days_since_ath_formatted} )
```

Then in the template you would want something like:

```
{% for currency in crypto_data_geckco %}

    All-Time Percentage: {{ currency.ath_change_percentage|intword }}%

    and passing the "days_since_ath_formatted" variable only accesses the last item in the list:

    Days since ATH: {{ currency.days_since_ath_formatted|timesince }}

{% endfor %}
```

I can't tell exactly but I guess your results_coin_list is a queryset in which case you could also add a property to the model directly

Comment: I already tried {{ currency.days_since_ath_formatted|timesince }} but that displays nothing on the Django template. Whereas {{ days_since_ath_formatted|timesince }} displays "1 month, 2 weeks" which is the last element in the list from the json data request result. The issue is that the code isn't iterating over the list. It should show each unique date for each list element.

Comment: I've added an update showing a change to the view as well (none of this code has been tested)

Comment: currency['days_since_ath_formatted'] = from_string(days_since_ath[:-14], "%Y-%m-%d")
and then {{ currency.days_since_ath_formatted|timesince }} in the template worked just like you said! perfect!